# $http.post - faild to load resource

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, mysqli

when i try to post data to my sql db from angular js I allways get the error:

Faild to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

INSERT ERROR

Thank you for helping :)

function

```
$scope.add = function(){
   var data = {
     'id': '1',
     'x' : '0',
     'y' : '0'
   }
   $http.post("myip/insert.php", data)
      .success(function(data, status, header, config){
          console.log('INSERT SUCCESS');
      })
      .error(function(data, status, header, config){
          console.log('INSERT ERROR');
      });
}
```

insert.php (The insert works with static variables)

```
<?php
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "usr", "pw", "my_db");
 if($conn->connect_error)
 {
     die("Connection: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
 $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 $request = json_decode($postdata);
 $id = $request->id;
 $x = $request->x;
 $y = $request->y;
 $conn->query("INSERT INTO items VALUES('$id', '$x', '$y')") or die($conn->error);
 $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: That's a Chrome specific error response. What about other browsers?

Comment: I try to open Firefox in Visual Studio, but I dont find the option...  :D

Comment: Ok, its really a Chrome problem, Firefox works...
How can I ceal with it in Chrome?

Comment: You'll need to do a bunch of google-fu to get that answer.